# Adding multiple variables into a loop

Tags: r, loops

I've only been doing R for about three hours, so bear with me!

I have imported a csv into R Studio. The input dataset is a model output, which has some character "n/a" values in some columns. I have written this code (please tell me if it can be done better) that imports the data, converts a column to numeric after removing "n/a" values, than runs a histogram:

```
Run_name <- " NA NA"

infile <- paste0("P:/installed-packages",Run_name,".csv")
installed_packages <- read.csv(infile)
View(installed_packages)

installed_packages$net.costs..After. <- as.numeric(replace(installed_packages$net.costs..After.,installed_packages$net.costs..After.=="n/a", NA))


hist(installed_packages$net.costs..After.)
```

The next stage would be to include multiple variable names in place of the variable `net.costs..After.` using a loop, as other variables will contain these "n/a" values. Ideally this would be a table of variable names but for now a typed list of variable names would be a step in the right direction.

Any tips on doing this, or on improving how this process is done?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to specify the `NA` strings when reading in the data:

```
installed_packages <- read.csv(infile, na.strings = "n/a")
```

If you want to turn your solution into a loop, you can use:

```
for (col_ in c("net.costs..After.", "col2", "col3")){
  installed_packages[, col_] <- as.numeric(replace(installed_packages[, col_], installed_packages[, col_]=="n/a", NA))
}
```

Where `c("net.costs..After.", "col2", "col3")` is the vector holding the names of the column.